# Global functions in an iOS application

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I need to be able to check for internet connectivity / available updates within multiple views. What would be the best way to implement methods / functions (which carry out this function) that are accessible in numerous views?

Whether I can have a separate class that include these methods, that I use as and when needed? If that's at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to download `Reachability.h` amd `.m` file add add it in your project.
and use this line :

```
Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"google.com"];
 if ([reach isReachable]) {
     //Internet Available...
}
else
{
      //Internet Not Available
}
```

Comment: Why are you checking whether you can reach Google.com to see if you have an internet connection? At the least it should be the site that he need to connect to.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are doing for your internet connectivity, but if you use something like the [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com) library, then you set up singleton's for endpoints and use those for network operations. It also includes it's own reachability functionality that you can use to see whether a network connection is possible as well as block based methods for handing changes in the connectivity state (just as important as checking whether a network connection exists)

If you'd rather roll your own solutions. Have a look at [NPReachability](https://github.com/Abizern/NPReachability). It's an extension to the Apple's Reachability class that provides KVO, blocks, and ARC support.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways possible. The singleton is a good idea, if your functions need to store any data. If not, you can just make a class that has only static methods (+ prefix). Then import that class from any file that needs it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ARC compatible version of Reachability: https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability.  In each view you want to check for internet in, you can add this to the viewDidLoad method:
// allocate a reachability object

```
Reachability* reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"http://thewebsiteyouareusing.com"];

// set the blocks 
reach.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
{
    // It works
};

reach.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
{
    // Uh oh, it doesn't work
};

[reach startNotifier];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no global methods provided by Apples Libraries and Frameworks you could directly use.

### Internet connection check

To **check the internet connection** you can use the [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Classes_Reachability_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Classes_Reachability_h-DontLinkElementID_5) class from [the Reachability example from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17010678/1578508)

```
Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"google.com"];
 if ([reach isReachable]) {
     //Internet Available...
}
else
{
      //Internet Not Available
}
```

Or use one of the other Open-Source Frameworks:

- https://github.com/kstenerud/KSReachability
- https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability
- https://github.com/GlennChiu/GCNetworkReachability

Little github search:

- https://github.com/search?q=ios+reachability&ref=cmdform

### Available App Updates Check

To check for **available App updates** you could use one of the available Open-Source Frameworks.
Like:

- https://github.com/gcerquant/UpdateKit
- https://github.com/Handelabra/HSLUpdateChecker
- https://github.com/y0n3l/LGStoreUpdateReminder

Answer (score -1):

One way is to add a variable to your app delegate. You can then access it anywhere using:

```
MyAppDelegate *app = (MyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication shared].delegate;
if (app.myInternetVariable) {
    // etc...
}
```

Another way is to use a singleton to store all your application data.

Comment: Storing variables in the Application Delegate is bad practice from an OO point of view. You are effectively using it like a singleton, and although they are useful when you really need them, they get used far too often as a lazy way of not thinking about an application's design. Also, the question is about connectivity, not singletons.